# see and change what triggers if statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm new to PHP so this might be a dumb question. I'm not sure how to name it or whether you can even do something like that but I have been wondering if I could see and change what variable triggers "if" statement.

For example if I have such code:

```php
if ($a == 1 || $b == 1 || $c == 1) {
    //find which variable has triggered it and change only this variable to something else, (leave other untouched)
    $this = 2;
}
```

or do I have to do a separate if statement for each variable?

Cheers

Comment: What do you want to happen if more than one variable triggers the if statement?

Comment: @MarkBaker I would have to change all of the variables which trigger the statement to "2" in my case"

Comment: Then you really need separate if statements for each, because they're all actually doing something different.... if you were using an array with the three entries, then this would be much easier

Comment: Sidenote: You realize that `$this` is reserved specifically for OOP http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php and will throw you `Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this...`. If that's what you're trying to use right now, then it's failing you. @TomaszGolinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isset()` command in PHP.

Since only one is always `not null` just do:

```
if(isset($c)): echo 'C triggered this!'; endif;
if(isset($b)): echo 'B triggered this!'; endif;
//etc...
```

Or use the `switch` method:

```
switch($c){
   case 1: 'C triggered this';
   default: 'C did not trigger this';
}
```

Due to your comment, you can use nested `if` statements:

```
if($c != 1){
    echo 'C is not set.';
} else if($b != 1){
    echo 'B is not set.';
}
```

To ensure there all set and determine the ones that are not set:

```
if(!isset($c)):
   echo 'C is not set.';
endif;
if(!isset($b)):
   echo 'b is not set.';
endif;

// etc...
```

Structure to not do lots of if statements:

```
$check = array(
     'a' => 1,
     'b' => 2
     // ect...
)
$i = 0;
while($i != count($check)){
   if(!isset($check[$i])):
      $check[$i] = 2;
      $i++;
   endif;
endwhile;
```

Setting up your array could be done like this:

```
// your code, when you want to add to the array
// a =1, b =2 etc... (so ensure your functions run in chronological order

array_push($check, 1);
```

Then your array will look like this:

```
$check = array (
    1 => 1,
    2 => 1,
);
```

etc...

Hope this helped.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have given enough informations. There is a code before this function which defines all of the variables. Then let's say I have to check whether one of the variables == 1. if one of those variables don't then I have to change it. Therefore isset() won't work, as all of the variables are actually set.

Comment: will that also work if 2 of the variables are 1? or will it only run it for the first variable that has triggered it?

Comment: So you want to check if everyone is set?

Comment: basically I want to check every variable whether they == 1? if any of them are, then change them to 2

Comment: but I would rather not create each statement as I will have to repeat the each time as that would mean I will have 7 exactly the same if statements (1 for each variable)

Comment: Right, so why not create an array of the 7 things and check each index point in the array if its isset in a while statement? you should reconsider your structure

Comment: take a look at the last answer, that should solve your issue if you don't want to use loads of `if` statements - you need to reconsider your structure

Comment: hmmm use key => value in array as variables is a good idea. I didn't know that would work

Comment: How you create the array is what you need to consider, but if you have 7 variables and need to check if they're 1, then you must use `if` statements, and that means using 7 of them. Like I said, you need to revisit your planning if you don't want to do this. You can always use `array_push($check, 1);` when you want to add and instead of `a,b,c,d` have `1,2,3,4` etc..

Comment: ok, That last code will work great, thanks for helping me on that one!! :)